# Ivy dependency with changing="true" always downloads artifacts, even not changed

Tags: ivy

According to Ivy documentation dependency with **changing="true"** means the module can change even if the revision is the same. This is useful especially for integration.

Now, I expect the system is smart enough so it does not download artifacts every time.
It can compare, for example, **"publication"** timestamps in ivy.xml and download (and cache) only if necessary.

But this is not the case if the dependency has **rev="latest.integration"**. I see it downloads artifacts every time and I'm sure they were not changed. If I change "rev" to some exact revision, then it works as expected.

Is this expected behavior and do I have any chance to make it work with "latest.integration"?

I use Ivy 2.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obscure problem. Your report does appear to contradict a strict interpretation of how the [changing module](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/concept.html#change) functionality works.

I'd suggest raising a ticket on the ivy JIRA. Not an issue that can be solved here.

Comment: Yeah, Mark, I think you are right. I was just not sure if I maybe misinterpret the Ivy configuration guide. I'll file a bug, thanks.